# Moving Query from View to Model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two non-attached models - milestones and users. (My milestones actually belong to companies and companies have many milestones.)

Each milestone has a user who'd responsible for it - in my milestone form, I'm using the following to find and select users:

```
<%= f.input :milestone_user, :as => :select, :collection => User.find(:all, :order => "name ASC") %>
```

This gives me a user_id which I've converted in one view to a name as follows:

```
<%= User.find(milestone.milestone_user).name %>
```

This works fine but I want to use this in a few views now and don't like having the query in my views.

I have tried to move it into my User model but I don't know how to go about it.  I've tried this in the model:

```
  scope :username, lambda { where("id = milestone_user")}
```

And this in my view:

```
<%= User.username.first_name %>
```

But it complains about an undefined method for first_name..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused by the question, if you are storing a milestone_user field in your Milestone model, why don't you use belongs_to directly?

Comment: Maybe I need to reconsider this one... I didn't want tasks to be owned by anyone, but I guess they should be.

Comment: When you say you don't want Milestone's owned by Users, can you elaborate a little? Aren't you already storing the milestone_user in the Milestone model, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Hi spike. Milestones are actually owned by a company, they just have users who need to action them. Hence the lack of ownership. Does that help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your `Milestone` model:

```
def username
  User.find(milestone_user).try :name
end
```

and use it like this in your view:

```
<%= milestone.username %>
```

But this isn't efficient, the better way would be to stick `belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "milestone_user", :class_name => "User"` in your `Milestone` model. You won't have to fill the association, you still could create milestones without an assigned user.

The `belongs_to` would also allow you to use code like this in your views:

```
<%= milestone.user.name %>
```

without having to create additional methods for every user property that you'd like to access.

Answer (score 1):

Move the query in the action of the related controller:

```
@milestone_user=User.find(milestone.milestone_user)
```

And then use [try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) in the view

```
<%= @milestone_user.try(:name) %>
```

Comment: Thanks. Im a bit confused. What do you mean when you say 'move'. Do I put the top part in my model? J

Comment: Hi again :) Thanks, this doesn't work for me as I need to access from many different views, not just for milestones - hence putting it in model. Jx

Answer (score 1):

set the model to have a `default_scope => :order('name asc')`

In your controllers do `@users = User.all`

In your views use `collection_select` with `@users`

e.g. collection_select(:milestone, :user_id, @users, :id, :name )

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select for more info about

collection_select, grouped_collection_select, grouped_options_for_select and other helpers which have options like

'grouped_collection_select(object, method, collection, group_method, group_label_method, option_key_method, option_value_method, options = {}, html_options = {})'

Comment: Hi Michael, the problem isn't getting a list of users in my select dropdown - the problem I have is converting an id - in this case the user id stored as milestone_user to a real name. Have i misunderstood your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think associations should be like this:

```
class Milestone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_one :user
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :milestones
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :milestone
end
```

if you make association like above one then on the view side you can simply write

```
<%= @milestone.user.firstname%>
```

otherwise you can just modify your scope:

```
  scope :milestone_user, lambda { |user_id|
    where("id = ?",user_id)
  }
```

*Here I have just modify the name of scope.*

and call from view through passing the parameter.

```
<%= User.milestone_user(milestone.milestone_user).first_name %>
```

Also you can use delegate methods.

Comment: How is doing `User.milestone_user(milestone.milestone_user).first_name` different from `User.find(milestone.milestone_user).name` (which was the solution used by the OP)?

Comment: yes it was for OP, if don't want to modify the association or association is something else. then just pass the _milestone user id_ in scope.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question... And your solution with the scope won't work, scopes return relations, you would have to call it like this: `User.milestone_user(milestone.milestone_user).first.first_name`.

Comment: Yes, u r correct about the scope. thx for correction I missed that.What I want to say only about to pass the parameter when call the scope as she is using lambda. But I will prefer to correct the **associations** and use them instead of writing scope in such kind of scenario.